# Elixir & Phoenix. Mailgun hangs when sending email with an attachment

Tags: elixir, attachment, phoenix-framework, mailgun

I'm using Mailgun to send emails with Elixir & Phoenix. 
I was following [this](http://www.phoenixframework.org/docs/sending-email) tutorial all the way, and everything was fine in test mode. Here is the code that is responsible for sending emails with an attachment:

```
def send_message_with_file(name, phone, msg, file_path, file_name) do
    send_email to: @to,
    from: @from,
    subject: "New message. #{name}",
    text: "Name: #{name}\nPhone: #{phone}\nMessage:#{msg}",
    attachments: [%{path: file_path, filename: file_name}]
end
```

In production mode, when I'm trying to send an email with an attachment, it just hangs and does nothing. However, Emails without an attachment can be delivered. Any suggestions why it could happen?

Comment: where is it hanging? can you print the contents of `file_path` and `file_name`?

Comment: @StephenG for instance "/var/folders/3p/3trj48456_q0tm2kh8g70qjm0000gn/T//plug-1469/multipart-769096-849490-2" and
"89a3e7d0fc7144139f825e1103981561.png"

Comment: The `file_path` has to be the full file path, including the file name. The `file_name` field is just the file name used in the attached

Comment: Just for your future reference it's helpful when you say something is hanging if you tell us _where_ it's hanging up.  Don't assume that it's obvious.